# Continuations, coroutines, and tail-call optimization

Tags: scheme, tail-call, continuation

I am trying to learn continuations and use them to implement coroutines in Scheme.

I have two procedures (coroutines) `a` and `b`, and I switch between them in the following way:

```
;; c is a continuation.
(define (a c)
   ...
   ;; Switch to the other coroutine.
   (call/cc c)
   ...


(define (b c)
   ...
   ;; Switch to the other coroutine.
   (call/cc c)
   ...
```

I  start the execution with

```
(a b)
```

I have tested a small example and, indeed, the execution switches back and forth between the two procedures until one of the two terminates without calling the continuation it was given as an argument.

I have two questions:

1. Is my example an appropriate / idiomatic implementation of coroutines using continuations?
2. Is tail-call optimization mandatory for implementing coroutines with continuations? In my solution, switching too often between the two coroutines might cause a stack overflow if Scheme did not provide TCO. Are there other solutions that do not require TCO?

**EDIT**

Basile's comment seems to be sufficient to answer my question. The background of the question is that I would like this approach to implement coroutines in Python, where I do not have TCO.

Comment: Your first question is answerable with "yes" or "no."  Are you sure that's your question, or would you prefer a bit more explanation?

Comment: Your second question seems trivially answerable with "Not if the stack doesn't go too deep."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I have tried my example and it seems to work: the execution switches back and forth between the two coroutines, but I am not sure whether this solution is idiomatic in Scheme. Maybe there is a different and more idiomatic implementation of coroutines using continuations.

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if there does not exist an alternative implementation that does not require TCO: I think such an implementation does not exist, but I am not sure. I would like to use a similar solution in another language and I hoped there does exist a solution that works without TCO.

Comment: Why would you deliberately seek out a solution that's not tail-call optimized?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Maybe I have formulated my question in the wrong way. What I mean is that I would like to find a solution that will work even without TCO. This would be useful e.g. if I wanted to use continuations to implement coroutines in Python.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: My question has a much simpler answer than I initially thought. If you wrote your comment as an answer I would mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented:

- yes, your example is an appropriate implementation of coroutines using continuations.
- yes, tail-call optimization is mandatory for implementing coroutines with continuations.

Comment: Thanks, I am not an expert with continuation and it is good to know that I am on a good track.